# How to add values to the battery consuming page

Tags: android, battery

I’m trying to understand how the settings -> battery page works (The one where it shows the different features that consume the battery, for example “screen – 70%, Bluetooth – 20%”). Are those default values or real-time calculated ones? Can anybody direct me to the class / classes that are building that page?

And one last question: If I want to install a new feature that will consume battery life (not a user app, but more of a system app that is a CPU consuming feature) , will it be shown there without me inserting it into the list programmatically?

Thanx a lot!

Comment: I think you cant install a system app unless your phone is rooted :)

Comment: Forgot to mention - It is rooted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Settings is an app that is written like normal application http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html.

`screen – 70%, Bluetooth – 20%`
It is not harcoded, It is based on some calculation on battery consumption, For eg: If you change your brightness your screen consumption should reduce. In `emulator` it is `hardcoded`.

```
 If I want to install a new feature that will consume battery life (not a user app, but more  of a system app that is a CPU consuming feature) , will it be shown there without me inserting it into the list programmatically?
```

I think you know that each and every app in the device is consuming battery , If your `app` should be listed under battery consumption seperately , then you should create a `settings` app for the phone.

**UPDATE**

As far i understood battery usage is associated with the internal package `"com.android.os.internal"`

Since you are rooted: you can access that and verify the code as you need :) ,Not sure about that , any way that's the way i found till now. Will give you update if anything better is found.

Comment: Are you sure the system won't add my app automatically to the existing battery settings list? After all, it is one of apps that is currentely consuming battery...

Comment: Yes, There are lot of other apps in system which is not added battery consuming, Yours will be listed under that

Comment: I see… Do you happen to know how can I add my app to the list? Or how to calculate how much it’s consuming?

Comment: Thanx!
I also found \packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings\fuelgauge\PowerUsageSummary.java which “Displays a list of apps and subsystems that consume power, ordered by how much power was consumed since the last time it was unplugged.”… It’s a bit hard for me to understand its content as I’m pretty new to android core code, but I’ll try to insert my code in one of those classes :)

Comment: Yeah try , u wl get it, all the best